# AWS EC2 S3 Conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

Hi i'm having a big trouble creating an EC2 instance that hosts an AngularJs app, to cut it short i have an EC2 instance with elastic ip and domain name `http://dev.mydomain.net` (machine has Nginx installed) my workspace is copied by Jenkins to S3 bucket named `S3.dev.mydomain.net` backed by a CDN distribution , my target is to create a new domain name `(dev2.mydomain.net)` so i created an image from first instance along with another S3 bucket and it's CDN , the problem is that whenever i tried to access Angular App from outside using `http://dev2.mydomain.net` i got redirected to Nginx welcome page! also whenever i tried to access App with newly created instance public dns i got catched by certificate `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Give that newly created instance has same security profile as original one, i also navigated all AWS services to know actually how `http:dev.mydomain.net` got linked to elastic ip of original instance but i didn't got it, any idea about what i have missed

update: Nginx conf at original instance:

```
user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    133916;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

include       conf.d/*.conf;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default     "upgrade";
}

server {
    listen        80 default_server;
    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    client_header_timeout 60;
    client_body_timeout   60;
    keepalive_timeout     60;
    gzip                  off;
    gzip_comp_level       4;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
    include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
 }
}
```

Comment: Compare your nginx a vhost settings. The certificate either is served directly by nginx or by a load balancer

Comment: added Nginx conf for original instance

Comment: This is a beanstalk environment?

Comment: Can you try accessing the old EC2 with public DNS and tell us what happens?

Comment: it's banned by S3 CORS policy

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of your old and new set up. There are a few things that needs to be clear to work out whats going wrong in your setup.

1. Where is your cert installed?
2. Is the cert you are using a wildcard cert?
2. Where is your static content served from?
3. How have you used CDN in your set up?
4. Where is your angular making calls to? i.e. old or new?

Comment: i have my ssl certiticate common name *.mydomain.net , after registering new sub-domain as web.scd.mydomain.net i got banned by browser for not secure domain, is it's required to have only 2 dots to make the certificate happy ?